# display all the layout available programmatically

Tags: android, android-layout, layout

I am trying to display all layout programmatically
    actually i can do it in  pure java but not in android

here is my first class:

```
public DiskFileExplorer(String path, Boolean subFolder) {
    super();
    this.initialpath = path;
    this.recursivePath = subFolder;
}

public String[] list() {
    return this.listDirectory(this.initialpath);
}

@SuppressWarnings("null")
private String [] listDirectory(String dir) {
    String[] values = null;
    File file = new File(dir);
    File[] files = file.listFiles();
    if (files != null) {
        for (int i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
            if (files[i].isDirectory() == true) {
                //Log.v("Dossier" , files[i].getAbsolutePath());
                this.dircount++;
            } 
            else {
                //Log.v("Fichier" ,files[i].getName());
                values[i] = files[i].getName();
                this.filecount++;
            }
            if (files[i].isDirectory() == true && this.recursivePath == true) {
                this.listDirectory(files[i].getAbsolutePath());
            }
        }
    }
    return values;
}
```

and the second one:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    public String []DiskFileExplorer(String path, Boolean subFolder){
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.mylist);
        String pathToExplore = "./res/layout";
        DiskFileExplorer d_expl = new DiskFileExplorer(pathToExplore,true);
        String[] values = d_expl.list();
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, android.R.id.text1, values);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter); 
    }
}
```

and my xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/mylist"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
    </ListView>

</LinearLayout>
```

and eveentually the pure java class that can do what i want to do in android:

```
import java.io.File;

/**
 * Lister le contenu d'un répertoire
 * @author fobec 2010
 */
public class DiskFileExplorer {

    private String initialpath = " ";
    private Boolean recursivePath = false;
    public int filecount = 0;
    public int dircount = 0;

   /**
    * Constructeur
    * @param path chemin du répertoire
    * @param subFolder analyse des sous dossiers
    */
    public DiskFileExplorer(String path, Boolean subFolder) {
        super();
        this.initialpath = path;
        this.recursivePath = subFolder;
    }

    public void list() {
        this.listDirectory(this.initialpath);
    }

    private  void listDirectory(String dir) {
        File file = new File(dir);
        File[] files = file.listFiles();

        if (files != null) {
            for (int i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
                if (files[i].isDirectory() == true) {
                    System.out.println("Dossier" + files[i].getAbsolutePath());
                    this.dircount++;
                } else {
                    System.out.println("" + files[i].getName());

                    this.filecount++;
                }
                if (files[i].isDirectory() == true && this.recursivePath == true) {
                    this.listDirectory(files[i].getAbsolutePath());
                }
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * Exemple : lister les fichiers dans tous les sous-dossiers
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String pathToExplore = "C:/Users/R_nkusi/workspace/Copy of AppList_bis/res/layout";
        DiskFileExplorer diskFileExplorer = new DiskFileExplorer(pathToExplore, true);
        Long start = System.currentTimeMillis();

        diskFileExplorer.list();

        System.out.println("----------");
        System.out.println("Analyse de " + pathToExplore + " en " + (System.currentTimeMillis() - start) + " mses");
        System.out.println(diskFileExplorer.dircount + " dossiers");
        System.out.println(diskFileExplorer.filecount + " fichiers");
    }
}
```

You have to change of course the"pathToExplore" and give one that exists in your own computer.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Is it a file explorer you want to create?

Comment: my problem is that i can't translate my java code that's running perfectly in android

Comment: yeah ,i want to create a file explorer to be able to display all the  available layout of my project

Comment: You do realize that the XML files are not actually `File`s? You won't find them on your mobile phone. When you build your project, all resource files get pre-baked resource IDs

Comment: no i didn't !so isn't a way i can display all my layout programmatically?

Comment: I dont think you can show the xml files at runtime. This is also the reason why you cant load XML layout files from some external server. To see what i mean, extract an .apk file and check the /res/layout/*.xml files

Comment: All  i want to do in android is exacatly what my pure java class is doing,if you have in android project in your camputer and you give the right path it will diplay all files at the console

Comment: It seems to be possible, contrary to what ive said. Ill check it out.

Comment: It's possible, but not through your filesystem, because all layout xml files are compiled. Check my updated answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can read out your own XML layout files, but you cant find it in your filesystem, because it's all compiled, thus not human readable.

Get all layout resource id's and their actual names:

```
void getIds() {
    Field[] ID_Fields = R.layout.class.getFields();
    int[] resArray = new int[ID_Fields.length];
    for(int i = 0; i < ID_Fields.length; i++)
        try {
            resArray[i] = ID_Fields[i].getInt(null);
            System.out.println(resArray[i] + " : " + getResources().getResourceEntryName(resArray[i]));
            getEventsFromAnXML(getResources().getXml(resArray[i])); //I'll show this later
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
}
```

However, you need to parse the XML yourself. Here's a small example:

```
private String getEventsFromAnXML(XmlResourceParser xpp) throws XmlPullParserException, IOException {
    StringBuffer stringBuffer = new StringBuffer();
    xpp.next();
    int eventType = xpp.getEventType();
    while (eventType != XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT) {
        if(eventType == XmlPullParser.START_DOCUMENT) {
            stringBuffer.append("--- Start XML ---");
        }
        else if(eventType == XmlPullParser.START_TAG) {
            stringBuffer.append("\nSTART_TAG: "+xpp.getName());
        }
        else if(eventType == XmlPullParser.END_TAG) {
            stringBuffer.append("\nEND_TAG: "+xpp.getName());
        }
        else if(eventType == XmlPullParser.TEXT) {
            stringBuffer.append("\nTEXT: "+xpp.getText());
        }
        eventType = xpp.next();
    }
    stringBuffer.append("\n--- End XML ---");
    System.out.println(stringBuffer.toString());
    return stringBuffer.toString();
}
```

I hope these pieces of code will help you get to where you want.

```
new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
.setTitle("Seen?")
.setMessage("Some message.")
.setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) { 
        // ok
    }
 })
.setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) { 
        // no
    }
 })
 .show();
```

Comment: Thank you for your help but i don't want read the xml layout but just get only their name

Comment: @Bob that possible with the top method (`getIds()`), specifically the line in which you see `getResources().getResourceEntryName(resArray[i])`.

Comment: Christiaan i tried to use getIds,i only change system.out.println by Log.v but it doesn't show anything

Comment: @Bob this works perfectly for me though. Try to add a Toast, and don't `Log.v`, Eclipse tends to filter verbose debug info. Use `Log.w`, `Log.d` or `Log.e` (I like e and w because you can spot em so easy in logcat). And be sure to actually have layout xml files.

Comment: thank you Christiaan !it shows all my layout in logcat but i would like to show it in alertdialog that doesn't appear!

Comment: @Bob What the heck is an alertdialog that doesn't appear and why would you want an alertdialog but not show it? PS: see edit for how to show an alertdialog.

Comment: That 's true it works ,but the button i am using to run that piece of code comes from a menu(written in xml) and when i tried to create an alertdialogue to display it my alertdialogue doesn't appear. why?

Comment: @Bob This seems to be way out of the scope of your original question. Search stackoverflow for AlertDialogs, although the piece of code shown in my answer works just fine. I suspect you forgot `.show()`. And remember that I can't adequately answer this question without the source code. I'd, however, appreciate it if you could accept my answer.

Comment: Oh sorry about that, i really appreaciate your answer Dank U

Comment: If you can't get it fixed by searching StackOverflow a little, make it another question, I'd be happy to help, but it's getting a little messy here. And to keep SO clean and organized, mark the answer as accepted (het oningevulde vinkje naast het begin van mijn antwoord.)

Comment: just answering if it was helpful?if it's that i've just done it

Comment: yeah i find the way to accept your answer,again thank you about the alertdialogue i found a another way to display it using  a layout